# How to run Locust tests directly from Python (without terminal)

Tags: python, testing, aws-lambda, load-testing, locust

Is it possible to run Locust tests from inline code without access to the shell? I am trying to deploy an AWS Lambda-based backend for my application to run load tests. I have not been able to find any documentation about running tests directly from the Python file without using the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the Locust docs, though it's not framed quite as you are phrasing it.

"It is possible to start a load test from your own Python code, instead of running Locust using the locust command."

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/use-as-lib.html

Comment: Thanks a ton! I looked for hours and could not find this.